# Powerapps - filter 2 columns at the same time

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I built gallery on `oracle` table and currently filtering on one column which  is a primary key. I would like my app to filter on 2 columns. Double filtering on same table and 2 columns.

I tried using this and it does not work

```
Filter('[POC].[VIATRM_BILLING]',StartsWith(PID,TextSearchBox1_1.Text) And EndsWith(PROGRAM_ID,TextSearchBox1_1.Text))
```

Comment: any followup questions?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `&&` instead of `And` (should not be a problem as both must work, I'm just curious :)).

```
Filter('[POC].[VIATRM_BILLING]', StartsWith(PID,TextSearchBox1_1.Text) && EndsWith(PROGRAM_ID,TextSearchBox1_1.Text))
```

If not, you can put multiple conditions using comma.

```
Filter(tablename, StartsWith(fieldname, TextInput1.Text),
                 EndWith(fieldname, TextInput1.Text)
      )
```

[Reference](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Search-function-that-can-look-for-more-than-one-part-of-a-string/td-p/392591)